# How to use Chef cron resource to run in minute intervals

Tags: chef

Is it possible to set cron to run per minute? I have tried two ways below with no luck. I have reviewed the documentation: https://docs.chef.io/resources/cron. The way the documents reads to me is that I can only run cron in a specific minute within a specific hour. Like 8:05. Rather than every single 5 minutes.

```
  cron 'Check-In to Chef Manage every minute' do
      minute '*'
      command 'chef-client'
      action :create
    end
```

```
  cron 'Check-In to Chef Manage every minute' do
      minute '0'
      command 'chef-client'
      action :create
    end
```

Comment: The cron resource really maps what a crontab entry does, hence why it accepts a string, so `minute '*/5'` or `minute '0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55'` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is in the comments by Tensibai. The following worked:

```
cron 'Check-In to Chef Manage every 5 minutes' do
  minute '*/5'
  command 'chef-client'
  action :create
end
```